# Replace zero or empty displayed prices with a custom text label in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I've added this code which works for empty price fields, but I also need it to work for values of 0.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_empty_price_html', 'custom_call_for_price');

function custom_call_for_price() {

    return 'Enquire';
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is the complete way to do it for BOTH **empty** and **zero** displayed prices, so this code replace also your actual code (to be removed).

It handle simple, variable and variation displayed prices (for BOTH **empty** and **zero** displayed prices):

```
// Variable and simple product displayed prices
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'empty_and_zero_price_html', 20, 2 );
function empty_and_zero_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    $empty_price = __('Enquire', 'woocommerce');

    if( $product->is_type('variable') )
    {
        $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );

        if ( empty( $prices['price'] ) ) {
            return $empty_price; // <=== HERE below for empty price
        } else {
            $min_price     = current( $prices['price'] );
            $max_price     = end( $prices['price'] );
            if ( $min_price === $max_price && 0 == $min_price ) {
                return $empty_price; // <=== HERE for zero price
            }
            elseif ( $min_price !== $max_price && 0 == $min_price ) {
                return wc_price( $max_price );
            }
        }
    }
    elseif( $product->is_type('simple') )
    {
        if ( '' === $product->get_price() || 0 == $product->get_price() ) {
            return $empty_price; // <=== HERE for empty and zero prices
        }
    }
    return $price;
}

// Product Variation displayed prices
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'empty_and_zero_variation_prices_html', 10, 3);
function empty_and_zero_variation_prices_html( $data, $product, $variation ) {

    if( '' === $variation->get_price() || 0 == $variation->get_price() )
        $data['price_html'] = __('Enquire', 'woocommerce'); // <=== HERE for empty and zero prices

    return $data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I've managed to use this code to remove the price altogether by simply replacing 'enquire' with a space. Is there any way for this to remove the add to cart button as well as the price?

Comment: How do I modify the code so that if the shipping cost is empty, the price of the product is not displayed.

Comment: @VictorDanielWitoszek… As shipping costs are only available when at least a product has been added to cart and when a customer has selected a shipping method (and defined before its shipping address (shipping zone)), you can't really use those hooks for that…