# Restrict a custom code to affect only the WooCommerce frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a code that works well to display a custom text instead of the price for products that don't have a price or have a price of zero value. It's working well in the frontend but in the backend it is replacing the price value in the WooCommerce products list.

How can I restrict this code to affect only the frontend of WooCommerce?

```
// Variable and simple product displayed prices
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'empty_and_zero_price_html', 20, 2 );
function empty_and_zero_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    $empty_price = __('Enquire', 'woocommerce');

    if( $product->is_type('variable') )
    {
        $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );

        if ( empty( $prices['price'] ) ) {
            return $empty_price; // <=== HERE below for empty price
        } else {
            $min_price     = current( $prices['price'] );
            $max_price     = end( $prices['price'] );
            if ( $min_price === $max_price && 0 == $min_price ) {
                return $empty_price; // <=== HERE for zero price
            }
            elseif ( $min_price !== $max_price && 0 == $min_price ) {
                return wc_price( $max_price );
            }
        }
    }
    elseif( $product->is_type('simple') )
    {
        if ( '' === $product->get_price() || 0 == $product->get_price() ) {
            return $empty_price; // <=== HERE for empty and zero prices
        }
    }
    return $price;
}

// Product Variation displayed prices
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'empty_and_zero_variation_prices_html', 10, 3);
function empty_and_zero_variation_prices_html( $data, $product, $variation ) {

    if( '' === $variation->get_price() || 0 == $variation->get_price() )
        $data['price_html'] = __('Enquire', 'woocommerce'); // <=== HERE for empty and zero prices

    return $data;
}
```

The code is inspired from this thread: [Replace zero or empty displayed prices with a custom text label in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083534/replace-zero-or-empty-displayed-prices-with-a-custom-text-label-in-woocommerce/77460775?noredirect=1#comment136561540_77460775)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an `IF` statement using `is_admin()` like:

```php
// Variable and simple product displayed prices
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'empty_and_zero_price_html', 20, 2 );
function empty_and_zero_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    // Not on backend
    if ( is_admin() ) return $price;

    $empty_price = __('Enquire', 'woocommerce');

    if( $product->is_type('variable') )
    {
        $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );

        if ( empty( $prices['price'] ) ) {
            return $empty_price; // <=== HERE below for empty price
        } else {
            $min_price     = current( $prices['price'] );
            $max_price     = end( $prices['price'] );
            if ( $min_price === $max_price && 0 == $min_price ) {
                return $empty_price; // <=== HERE for zero price
            }
            elseif ( $min_price !== $max_price && 0 == $min_price ) {
                return wc_price( $max_price );
            }
        }
    }
    elseif( $product->is_type('simple') )
    {
        if ( '' === $product->get_price() || 0 == $product->get_price() ) {
            return $empty_price; // <=== HERE for empty and zero prices
        }
    }
    return $price;
}

// Product Variation displayed prices
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'empty_and_zero_variation_prices_html', 10, 3);
function empty_and_zero_variation_prices_html( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    // Not on backend
    if ( is_admin() ) return $data;

    if( '' === $variation->get_price() || 0 == $variation->get_price() )
        $data['price_html'] = __('Enquire', 'woocommerce'); // <=== HERE for empty and zero prices

    return $data;
}
```

I should solve your issue definitively.